# Safe to go above ninty degrees on hip abductor machine?

Tags: hip

Here is a picture of the machine:

> [image]

Is it safe to go above ninty degrees angle between the thighs on this machine? It was given as instruction, but I didn't feel any particular pain going above it.

Edit: I tried searching about this question on r/Fitness, and there seems to be no threads discussing this particular issue

Comment: Please review the [How do I ask a good question?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) article in the [help]. In particular, I’ve noticed many of your questions do not appear to include any research done beforehand. What work if you done to find the answer yourself? Why didn’t it answer your question? Please try to do some research on your own before asking questions here, so that you can include it in your question posts.

Comment: I don't think this particular point has been discussed anywhere on reddit @ThomasMarkov

Comment: Neither on Youtube as far my searching finds. If you were to suggest some other places to search other than this, I would surely do it

Comment: Reddit is hardly a good resource, and there’s a big wide internet out there.

Comment: Also, if you can't find any discussion or explanation of a claim that something is unsafe, that should lead you to conclude that the claim of it being unsafe was made up and should be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not seen a machine with a such a warning placed on it before. I can personally vouch for having worked at a much higher angle than that without injury, and of course the machines themselves are generally set up so that such higher angles can be dialed in. In quickly researching this, I did find that, for non-machine abduction exercises, it's pretty common for them to suggest a 90 degree *knee* angle, which makes me wonder if perhaps this is a case of confusion leading to them posting the wrong advice (which would require them making two errors that add up to this, but humans constantly astound me).

As to whether it is safe for an individual, for abduction, it's generally not an issue since you can only go as far as your flexibility and muscle strength will take you. Some machines allow switching to hip adduction, pushing inwards, and I'd advise more caution with larger angles, particularly once you add weight. That said, I don't know of any hard and fast rules for a particular angle.